# URI For Excel Services REST API

Tags: excel, api, rest, sharepoint-online

I want to access data through API, but it returns 403 Forbidden from postman and error from web browser.

What I've tried:
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/software/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/My%20Folder/My%20File.xlsx

What would be the correct excel services URL? Thanks a lot.

My reference:

[Basic URL structure and path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/basic-uri-structure-and-path)

[Sample URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sample-uri-for-excel-services-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

The url should be like this:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Shared%20Documents/test/Book1.xlsx/model
```

It should work in IE.